# Jmx remote connection to Openshift WildFly

Tags: java, openshift, jmx, wildfly

I trying to connect remote jvm, used jvisualvm.
I started server with this parameters:

```
-Dcom.sunmanagement.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=15001 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

and i have this error:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when i removed this parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

i have another error, like this:

```
Error: Password file not found: /var/lib/openshift/5406e3aa500446a793000178/
wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password
```

Question. How configure server for jmx remote connetion?
I used action hooks for init java parameters.

**May be exists another tools for monitoring jvm?**

Comment: May be it not possible. The answer know only openshift developers.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that trying to use jmx remoting bind per default to 0.0.0.0 (aka all network interfaces). However, on Openshift you can only bind to $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP. The error seems cryptic, but that might be caused by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048050.